# Lattice parameters and basis vectors of crystal lattice structures

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

Does someone know where I can find lattice parameters and basis vectors of crystal lattice structures (Strukturbericht Designation) for different materials?

In particular I am searching the lattice parameters and the atomic basis of the Strukturbericht Designation B1, B2, B16, B27, and B33 of PbSe (lead selenide).

I already found this page, https://homepage.univie.ac.at/michael.leitner/lattice/struk/btype.html, however, there the lattice parameters and the atomic basis is only given for a prototype of a structure.

Isn't there a general reference?

Comment: I see three PbSe entries in [Crystallography Open Database](http://www.crystallography.net), but all in the same spacegroup:  [1537678](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/1537678.html),  [9011359](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/9011359.html),  [9011360](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/9011360.html). I could overlook something, I'm not really familiar with COD.

Comment: And Googling 'crystal structure PbSe' pulls up various suggestions of papers. A good science database search yields many others. One to start with would be  S V Streltsov1, A Yu Manakov2, A P Vokhmyanin1, S V Ovsyannikov1 and V V Shchennikov1

Published 24 August 2009 • IOP Publishing Ltd
Journal of Physics: Condensed Matter, Volume 21, Number 38  and references therein.

Comment: Thank you very much. I also tried it this way but in most of the papers they only write the lattice parameters but not the atom positions. That was a bit frustrating so I thought there must be another data base where the people get the positions from...

Comment: The cif files in COD have positions, in this case `Pb 0 0 0` and `Se 0.5 0.5 0.5`. Equivalent positions are not listed; they are implied by the space group. If you open such a CIF file in a viewer that understands this format you will see all atoms.